# Prove that $(H, \circ)$ is a subgroup of $(G, \circ)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $(G, \circ)$ be a group and $(H, \circ)$ be a non-empty subset of $G$. A relation $\rho$ defined by $$a\rho b ~~iff~~ a\circ b^{-1}\in H~~ for ~~a, b\in G,$$ is an equivalence relation on G. Prove that $(H, \circ)$ is a subgroup of $(G, \circ)$.

I can prove that $\rho$ is an equivalence relation. But the problem is to prove $(H, \circ)$ is a subgroup of $(G, \circ)$. Then why "$\rho$ is an equivalence relation" is required to mention in the problem.

Also $(H, \circ)$ is a subgroup of $(G, \circ)$ if $a, b\in H \implies a\circ b^{-1}\in H$ is a standard theorem on the chapter SUBGROUP. Then what is left to the problem?

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you want to use the composition symbol for your multiplication: $a\circ b$. If so, the symbol is `\circ`.

Comment: You cannot PROVE that $\rho$ is an equivalence relation; that is an assumption of the problem which is necessary to show that H is a subgroup.

Comment: If you proved $\rho$ is an equivalence relation without assuming that $H$ is a subgroup your proof was wrong. If you did assume $H$ is a subgroup you're confused about the logic. You're _given_ that $\rho$ is an equivalence relation, and you have to _prove_ that $H$ is a subgroup.

Comment: Also note that not all pairs in G are related by $\rho$; the goal is to prove that all pairs in $H$ are indeed related by $\rho$, when you can then apply the theorem that you stated.

Comment: @Aravind Yes. I now understand. You are right. Would you suggest how to prove this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we are being told is that the set $H$ makes $\rho$ an equivalence relation. I other words, when $\rho$ is defined as above we have that $\rho$ is an equivalence relation.

We have to prove this implies $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

We can use the subgroup criterion, so all we have to prove is $e\in H$ and that  if $a,b\in H$ then $aob^{-1}\in H$.

Since we have $e\rho e$ by the reflexivity of $\rho$ we conclude $eoe^{-1}=e\in H$

Now let $a,b\in H$. Notice that we have $a\rho e$ since $ae^{-1}=a\in H$, similarly notice we have $b\rho e$ since $be^{-1}=b\in H$. Since $\rho$ is symmetric we also have $e\rho b$. Now, we have $a\rho e$ and $e\rho b$. So by transitivity we have $a\rho b$, and this implies $aob^{-1}\in H$ as desired.